# Not able to install ipa in iPhone using itms url

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The issue is I am able to install IPA sometimes and sometimes it is not showing alert which is raised by OS to install IPA.
Though the behavior is inconsistent, not able t conclude what is an issue. Same URL from the browser we are able to install.
Please anyone know anything about this, please update.

Code is below

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrlAsync(
                    downloadlink, options: new UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions()); to istall ipa.
```

URL format is itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=actualurl

Comment: Where does this URL lead you to? Is it a supported download for iOS? iOS does not allow downloading applications from non-trusted sources like for instance a google drive link!

Comment: @FreakyAli Thanks for your reply. URL is hosting to the internal app store. This was working fine previously but suddenly now stopped working.